# How do I return a list containing multiple lists?

Tags: python

I want my code to get multiple lists(multiple_list) and append them to one single list(single_list). I know there may be easier ways but I'm a beginner and I want to solve it with what I can do.

It returns the list (single_list) filled with empty lists(multiple_list), and not with numbers that are in the if statement.

```
def list_squared(m, n):
    multiple_list=[]
    single_list=[]
    for i in range (m, n+1):

        for j in range(1, i+1):
            if i%j == 0:
                multiple_list.append(j)

            single_list.append(multiple_list)

            multiple_list.clear()

    return single_list

print(list_squared(1,250))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close! Instead of appending and then immediately clearing the original list, just create a new list to append and leave the lists that go into the higher order list alone:

```
def list_squared(m, n):
    single_list=[]
    
    for i in range (m, n+1):
        multiple_list=[]
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            if i%j == 0:
                multiple_list.append(j)

        single_list.append(multiple_list)

    return single_list

print(list_squared(1,250))
```

To explain why you need to do this a little better, in Python, values are passed as a reference to the original value, so when you did `multiple_list.clear()` you cleared the *same* list that was just appended, and so your loop just adds that same list (`multiple_list`) to `single_list` every iteration of your outer loop instead of generating a new list for each iteration.

Comment: Thank you! I think it does work better now and I understood your explanation, however it still seem to print all the multiple lists a looot of times. Do you know what could it be? Or is it just me and if you run the code it works fine?

Comment: Ah yes, I edited my answer to change the nesting of `single_list.append(multiple_list)` instead of it getting appended on every iteration of the inner loop, now it will only be added once the inner loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super-compressed way of your question.

```
m=1
n=250
new_l=[[j for j in range(1,i+1) if i%j==0] for i in range(m,n+1)]
```

This is list comprehension, works same as your main code.
This is this traditional method:

```
def list_squared(m, n):
    single_list=[]
    for i in range (m, n+1):
        multiple_list=[]
        for j in range(1, i+1):
            if i%j == 0:
                multiple_list.append(j)
        single_list.append(multiple_list)
    return single_list
m=1
n=250
print(list_squared(1,250))
```

Comment: Thank you!! Everytime I see a solution of a problem that I just solved, there is one that only takes one line of code like this one. I think this one-line codes are much efficient and easier but one thing at a time, I will get into this and try to understand how this works too!

Comment: This is basically nested for loop where the first one is the inner for loop and the outer loop is the main loop